# Problem with fill the sms body in Androids' default sms Acvtivity

Tags: android, android-activity, sms

I have a problem with opening a default sms Activity.
I'm using the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"+contact));  
intent.putExtra("sms_body", R.string.sms);  
startActivity(intent);
```

It happens to fill the number but not body. Have you come across this problem? Or maybe you know other way to open default sms Activity with filled number and body?

**EDIT**
OK. What I found is that Android has problem with accessing the String in R file. What is the way to convert some R.string to String in code?

Answer (score 0):

So there is a way. Sorry for being stupid

```
intent.putExtra("sms_body", getString(R.string.sms));
```